# is there a formula that will allow me to pull data from one google sheet tab to another based on a if contains conditional

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a list of start dates in one tab in Google sheets. I want to pull only the start dates that reflect 2021 into a new tab, as well as pull the corresponding info for that entry from the other columns into the new tab.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11EjBY127olRNnu7a5D8zp8aOGDSg6cxJomsQwKoo990/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of satisfying your question. This is just one example.

use this query
`=query(A1:D6,"select A, B, C, D where year(A)=2021")`

---

**Sample data**

[image: sample]

---

**Queried data**

[image: after]